# Difference between Azure login.microsoftonline.com issuer and {tenant_name}.b2clogin.com

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I'm not getting what difference between these urls have as issuers:

[https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}/v2.0](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%7Btenant_id%7D/v2.0)

https://{tenant_name}.b2clogin.com/{tenant_id}/v2.0/

By the looks of these it seems they both points to same resources/jwt signaure keys but seems they are not. Can anyone explain?

Answer (score 0):

https:// login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}/v2.0 is the issuer when you use Azure AD Authentication. [Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-protocols#endpoints)

https://{tenant_name}.b2clogin.com/{tenant_id}/v2.0 is the issuer when you use Azure AD B2C Authentication. [Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tokens-overview#claims)

Refer to [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/overview) for an overview of Azure AD B2C

Comment: These do not explain the difference between signature keys and why are they difference from each other